# Android kotlin Webview cookies handling

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

When opening a **Webview** from my android app i'm prompt with privacy policy after i accept them and close and reopen the **Webview** i'm again prompt with the same privacy and policy.
If the user have already accepted privacy and policy i don't want it to be displayed again. Any idea how i can achieve that ?